# Reconstruct original sentence from smaller phrases?

Tags: ruby, string, nlp

I have an original sentence

```
sent = "For 15 years photographer Kari Greer has been documenting wildfires and the men and women who battle them."
```

and phrases:

```
phrases = [
  "For 15 years",
  "wildfires and the men and women who battle them",
  "has been documenting wildfires",
  "been documenting wildfires and the men and women who battle them",
  "documenting wildfires and the men and women who battle them",
  "them",
  "and the men and women who battle them",
  "battle them",
  "wildfires",
  "the men and women",
  "the men and women who battle them",
  "15 years",
  "photographer Kari Greer"
]
```

I want to reconstruct the original sentence from the phrases (without loosing any words) and store selected phrases in the new array keeping the order so that I get:

```
 result = [
   "For 15 years",
   "photographer Kari Greer",
   "has been documenting wildfires",
   "and the men and women who battle them"
]
```

**Edit**: It is important that the `result` has the minimum number of elements.

**Edit**: Here is the version of the answer code that works for the more complex case:

```
 sent ="Shes got six teeth Pink says of her 13-month-old daughter but shes not a biter"      
 phrases = ["her 13-month-old daughter", "she", "says of her 13-month-old daughter", "a biter", "got six teeth", "Pink", "of her 13-month-old daughter", "s not a biter", "She", "six teeth", "s got six teeth", "Shes got six"] 

def shortest(string, phrases)
 string = string.gsub(/\.|\n|\'|,|\?|!|:|;|'|"|`|\n|,|\?|!/, '')
 best_result = nil
 phrases.each do |phrase|
  if string.match(/#{phrase}/)
    result = [phrase] + shortest(string.sub(/#{phrase}/, "").strip, phrases)
        best_result = result  if (best_result.nil? || result.size < best_result.size) # && string == result.join(" ")
      end
    end
  best_result || []
end
```

Comment: You could iterate through `phrases` and search for the ones that are in `sent` to get an unordered `result` array.

Comment: order is really important. I know that all the phrases in the phrases array are present in the sentence.

Comment: Will order alone suffice or do you require `result` to have least number of elements ?

Comment: Least number is also important.

Comment: +1 Interesting question! Would you mind sharing the context/motivation for this?

Comment: sure - I am creating subtitles for videos.

Comment: Why not just store the original sentence?

Comment: well it's due to certain specifics of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def shortest(string, phrases)
  best_result = nil
  phrases.each do |phrase|
    if string.match(/\A#{phrase}/)
      result = [phrase] + shortest(string.sub(/\A#{phrase}/, "").strip, phrases)
      best_result = result if (best_result.nil? || result.size < best_result.size) && string.match(Regexp.new("\\A#{result.join("\\s?")}\\Z"))
    end
  end
  best_result || []
end
result = shortest(sent.gsub(/\./, ""), phrases)
```

**Edit:** Updated the algorithm to allow some phrases to not have spaces between them.

Comment: Hi, I am trying to apply your method to this example and can't quite understand why it does not work.. can you explain please? sent ="Shes got six teeth Pink says of her 13-month-old daughter but shes not a biter"  phrases = ["her 13-month-old daughter", "she", "says of her 13-month-old daughter", "a biter", "got six teeth", "Pink", "of her 13-month-old daughter", "s not a biter", "She", "six teeth", "s got six teeth", "Shes got six"]

Comment: The word "but" doesn't exist in any of your phrases, so that is the first problem.The other problem is that the algorithm I gave assumes spaces between the phrases. Let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Although, I have tried the new version with the sent / phrases from the above comment and it still returns empty array.. I have changed the code a little bit so that it works for this case, but it gets really slow and gets into the endless loop in some cases.. but maybe you can have a look at it (I will put it into the question)...

Comment: Your phrases array doesn't include the word "but" anywhere, so it is impossible to build that sentence without losing words. Add "but" to the phrases array and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
def solve arr
    len = arr.count
    (len - 1).downto(0) do |i|
        phrase = arr[0..i].join(" ")
        if $phrases.include?(phrase)
            return [phrase] if len - 1 == i
            ans = solve arr[(i + 1)..(len - 1)]
            return [phrase] + [ans] if ans.count != 0
        end
    end
    []
end

words = sent.gsub(".", "").split(" ")
res = solve words
puts res.flatten.inspect
```

This should work I think. It looks for the biggest phrase that matches and checks if the rest of the phrase can be broken into phrases.

There's probably a better way to do it but its 4 in the morning here...