# Find two phrases from the larger sentence with the least overlap

Tags: ruby, string, nlp

I have:

```
phrase = "will have to buy online pass from EA to play online but its in perfect condition" 

phrases = ["its",
"perfect condition",
"but its",
"in perfect condition",
"from EA",
"buy online pass from EA",
"to play online but its in perfect condition",
"online",
"online pass",
"play online but its in perfect condition",
"online but its",
"EA",
"will have to buy online pass from EA to play online but its in perfect condition",
"have to buy online pass from EA to play online but its in perfect condition",
"u",
"pass",
"to buy online pass from EA"]
```

I would like to find two phrases from the array that are within 6-10 words limit and have least overlap word-wise...

Something like:

```
result = ["to buy online pass from EA", "play online but its in perfect condition"]
```

would be perfect.. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: it was similar... you mean this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300921/reconstruct-original-sentence-from-smaller-phrases

Comment: Any two that don't overlap? In any order?

Comment: any order yes within 6<phrase.length<10

Comment: actually it would be great if the order is maintained..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
split_phrases = phrases.map {|phrase| phrase.split }

# find number of words of overlap between two word vectors
def overlap(p1,p2)
  s1 = p1.size
  s2 = p2.size

  # make p1 the longer phrase
  if s2 > s1
    s1,s2 = s2,s1
    p1,p2 = p2,p1
  end

  # check if p2 is entirely contained in p1
  return s2 if p1.each_cons(s2).any? {|p| p == p2}

  longest_prefix = (s2-1).downto(0).find { |len| p1.first(len) == p2.last(len) }
  longest_suffix = (s2-1).downto(0).find { |len| p2.first(len) == p1.last(len) }

  [longest_prefix, longest_suffix].max
end

def best_two_phrases_with_minimal_overlap(wphrases, minlen=6, maxlen=10)
  # reject too small or large phrases, evaluate every combination, order by word overlap
  scored_pairs = wphrases.
    select {|p| (minlen..maxlen).include? p.size}.
    combination(2).
    map { |pair| [ overlap(*pair), pair ] }.
    sort_by { |tuple| tuple.first }

  # consider all pairs with least word overlap
  least_overlap = scored_pairs.first.first
  least_overlap_pairs = scored_pairs.
    take_while {|tuple| tuple.first == least_overlap }.
    map {|tuple| tuple.last }

  # return longest pair with minimal overlap
  least_overlap_pairs.sort_by {|pair| pair.first.size + pair.last.size }.last
end

puts best_two_phrases_with_minimal_overlap(split_phrases).map{|p| p.join ' '}

# to play online but its in perfect condition
# to buy online pass from EA
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
result = Array.new
phrases.each do |p|
  result.push(p) if(phrase.include?(p) && (6..10).include?(p.split.size))
end 
#remove entries that are substr of others   
result.each do |r|
  result.delete(r) if (t = result.clone ; t.delete(r) ; t.any? {|v| v.include?(r)})
end   
print result.inspect 
#["to play online but its in perfect condition", "to buy online pass from EA"]
```

Comment: This found a good answer, but misses exclusions where the phrases overlap at head and tail but aren't fully contained in each other.